# Mercurial Commit several changesets as one single changeset

Tags: mercurial

I have a following question. Now, suppose we have two repositories, a stable one and a developer one (that is the child of the central). Suppose I made several commits (about ten) in the developer repository while debugging and cleaning the feature I am working on.

Suppose I finished working with the feature and I push it to the central repository. Everything is fine, however, I would like to have an ability to somehow filter the log of the central repository. As far as I understand it will show info about all the commits I made to the developer repository. Is there a possibility to somehow filter that and display the info just about the push in the history log? I mean see it as the single big commit - a stable one.

I understand that inside the central repository the changesets will not be merged into a single one, what I would like to see is the history of the *pushes*, not the *changesets*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can't have local repo and push-target with **different history** - you'll have to build intermediate local repo for history-strip
2. In addition to the link Raghuram has provided, I'll recall [Histedit extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension).

Comment: Histedit did what I wanted. I recommend to make a backup copy of the project before using it, however.

Answer (score 1):

The history of pushes isn't recorded anywhere as far as I know. The only thing you could do is use a hook on the central repository to log them yourself, but it'll be separate and not part of the normal flow.

The only thing which is slightly related is `hg log -m` which shows only the merges. Considering there tends to be a merge at the end of any development branch this can be useful, but only if people put a useful commit message on their merge rather than just 'Merge' which is what people seem to do.

Answer (score 1):

There may be 2 solutions I could think of. Both have their disadvantages, however.

Assuming your development tip is "D" and stable tip is "S".

1) You can use rebase extension for that. First, make a clone of you developer repo and run:

```
hg -b <D> -d <S> --collapse --detach
```

Make sure you use the latest version of Mercurial (stable tip). There were several fixes very recently which affects this specific use of rebase. A disadvantage is that you'll have to merge with every revision in your development branch separately.

2) You can merge your repos as usual, but instead of commiting your merge use a following hack. 
ss

```
hg update <S>
hg merge <D>
...resolve conflicts if necessary...
...but do not commit!...
hg debugsetparents <S>
hg commit -m "Squash merge from devel branch"
```

This way we force to use only one parent for commit. This is a hack and therefore is not recommended. But it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking at how to [concatenate changesets](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConcatenatingChangesets).  The link provides multiple options.

Comment: No, that's not a solution, I don't want to concatenate them really inside the repository, since this would make a terrible mix and anarchy, if someone will try to push the changes again from developer to central. I just need to somehow handle the history for the central repo. I guess, maybe I should use some text utility tool to group the changes for different pushes, grouping them by push date to the central repo, that's all, I can suggest myself